# Fortran Sort Method Numerical recipies

Tags: sorting, segmentation-fault, fortran, fortran77

i m using C to Call Fortran, 
my fortran is calling sort() method

```
 *-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 * SUBROUTINE sort(A,n)
 * Subroutine de la librairie "Numerical Recipes"
 * (C) Copr. 1986-92 Numerical Recipes Software
 *-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      SUBROUTINE sort(arr,n)
      INTEGER n,M,NSTACK
      REAL arr(n)
      PARAMETER (M=7,NSTACK=50)
      INTEGER i,ir,j,jstack,k,l,istack(NSTACK)
      REAL a,temp
      jstack=0
      l=1
      ir=n
1     if(ir-l.lt.M)then
        do 12 j=l+1,ir
          a=arr(j)
          do 11 i=j-1,1,-1
            if(arr(i).le.a)goto 2
            arr(i+1)=arr(i)
11        continue
          i=0
2         arr(i+1)=a
12      continue
        if(jstack.eq.0)return
        ir=istack(jstack)
        l=istack(jstack-1)
        jstack=jstack-2
      else
        k=(l+ir)/2
        temp=arr(k)
        arr(k)=arr(l+1)
        arr(l+1)=temp
        if(arr(l+1).gt.arr(ir))then
          temp=arr(l+1)
          arr(l+1)=arr(ir)
          arr(ir)=temp
        endif
        if(arr(l).gt.arr(ir))then
          temp=arr(l)
          arr(l)=arr(ir)
          arr(ir)=temp
        endif
        if(arr(l+1).gt.arr(l))then
          temp=arr(l+1)
          arr(l+1)=arr(l)
          arr(l)=temp
        endif
        i=l+1
        j=ir
        a=arr(l)
3       continue
          i=i+1
        if(arr(i).lt.a)goto 3
4       continue
          j=j-1
        if(arr(j).gt.a)goto 4
        if(j.lt.i)goto 5
        temp=arr(i)
        arr(i)=arr(j)
        arr(j)=temp
        goto 3
5       arr(l)=arr(j)
        arr(j)=a
        jstack=jstack+2
        if(jstack.gt.NSTACK)pause 'NSTACK too small in sort'
        if(ir-i+1.ge.j-l)then
         istack(jstack)=ir
         istack(jstack-1)=i
         ir=j-1
       else
         istack(jstack)=j-1
         istack(jstack-1)=l
         l=i
       endif
     endif
     goto 1
     END
```

And if i call sort method many times, i have a segfault in this method :(

It's legacy code but i'm trust in it because it come from numerical recipies.
But i'm suspicious about some things, in particular this line :

```
if(jstack.gt.NSTACK)pause 'NSTACK too small in sort'
```

If i'm in this case, my programm will in pause? how it's possible that a sort method do this?

And if this line is suspicious, how can i trust the entire code?

does anyone know a problem with this sort subroutine? does anybody know another method to doing sort in fortran? Because i can replace this sort method by another one but i'm new in fortran and i can't write another one.

I add that no problem if i run this method in mono thread, but if i run it in multi thread environement, problem is here. sorry to don't mentionned when i wrote my question but i see this after writing it.

**DEBUG information**

```
current thread: t@41
  [1] __lwp_kill(0x0, 0x6, 0x0, 0x6, 0xffbffeff, 0x0), at 0xff2caa58
  [2] raise(0x6, 0x0, 0xff342f18, 0xff2aa378, 0xffffffff, 0x6), at 0xff265a5c
  [3] abort(0x7400, 0x1, 0x0, 0xfcb78, 0xff3413d8, 0x0), at 0xff24194c
  [4] os::abort(0x1, 0x0, 0xff011084, 0xfefdc000, 0x7d94, 0x7c00), at 0xfee7d3cc
  [5] VMError::report_and_die(0x0, 0xff038640, 0xff031ff4, 0x1, 0xfee81b94, 0xff031ff4), at 0xfef0cd58
  [6] JVM_handle_solaris_signal(0xb, 0xacffefe0, 0xacffed28, 0x8000, 0xff030fa0, 0x2013d8), at 0xfea73d48
  [7] __sighndlr(0xb, 0xacffefe0, 0xacffed28, 0xfea7325c, 0x0, 0x1), at 0xff2c6e78
  ---- called from signal handler with signal 11 (SIGSEGV) ------
  [8] sort_(0xfe2b1350, 0xfe2b135c, 0xfe2b1000, 0x1c00, 0x443bfc7b, 0xfe292484), at 0xfe27e498
  [9] mediane_(0xa9c1624c, 0xacfff2ac, 0xa9c16060, 0xa9c05c34, 0x0, 0x19), at 0xfe27a38c


(dbx) frame 8
0xfe27e498: sort_+0x01d8:       ld       [%l4 + %l1], %f4
(dbx) disassemble
0xff2caa58: __lwp_kill+0x0008:  bcc,a,pt  %icc,__lwp_kill+0x18  ! 0xff2caa68
0xff2caa5c: __lwp_kill+0x000c:  clr      %o0
0xff2caa60: __lwp_kill+0x0010:  cmp      %o0, 91
0xff2caa64: __lwp_kill+0x0014:  move     %icc,0x4, %o0
0xff2caa68: __lwp_kill+0x0018:  retl
0xff2caa6c: __lwp_kill+0x001c:  nop
0xff2caa70: __lwp_self       :  mov      164, %g1
0xff2caa74: __lwp_self+0x0004:  ta       %icc,0x00000008
0xff2caa78: __lwp_self+0x0008:  retl
0xff2caa7c: __lwp_self+0x000c:  nop
```

in m in solaris with dbx=> gdb on

i try to inspect adress but what can i type to have interesting informations?

After adding -g option to f90 compiler, in dbx i can see value or var and see the result:

```
t@88 (l@88) terminated by signal ABRT (Abort)
0xff2caa58: __lwp_kill+0x0008:  bcc,a,pt  %icc,__lwp_kill+0x18  ! 0xff2caa68
Current function is sort
  578           temp=arr(k)
(dbx) print n
n = 19
(dbx) print arr
arr =
    (1)    725.0666
    (2)    741.5034
    (3)    730.8196
    (4)    754.3707
    (5)    741.718
    (6)    741.718
    (7)    741.8914
    (8)    745.9141
    (9)    744.6705
    (10)    741.718
    (11)    745.8358
    (12)    743.3788
    (13)    746.2706
    (14)    746.2706
    (15)    750.1498
    (16)    754.3707
    (17)    754.3707
    (18)    754.3707
    (19)    748.2084
(dbx) print istack
istack =
    (1)    7
    (2)    12
    (3)    17
    (4)    18
    (5)    8
    (6)    9
    (7)    1
    (8)    4
    (9)    0
    (10)    0
    (11)    0
    (12)    0
    (13)    0
    (14)    0
    (15)    0
    (16)    0
    (17)    0
    (18)    0
    (19)    0
    (20)    0
    (21)    0
    (22)    0
    (23)    0
    (24)    0
    (25)    0
    (26)    0
    (27)    0
    (28)    0
    (29)    0
    (30)    0
    (31)    0
    (32)    0
    (33)    0
    (34)    0
    (35)    0
    (36)    0
    (37)    0
    (38)    0
    (39)    0
    (40)    0
    (41)    0
    (42)    0
    (43)    0
    (44)    0
    (45)    0
    (46)    0
    (47)    0
    (48)    0
    (49)    0
    (50)    0
(dbx) print jstack
jstack = -31648
(dbx)
```

how its possible taht jstack have a -31648 val! istack have only 50 element and istack(jstack) retrun me a abd value! how its possible? :)
thanks by advance

Comment: Did you try to replace the `pause` with a `write` statement? The `pause` statement is officially deleted since Fortran 95 (but still supported by many compilers). Which compiler do you use?

Comment: please run the code in a debugger to point a line where it segfaults.

Comment: "does anybody know another method to doing sort in fortran?" Of course, there are many methods. Write your own bubble sort, heap sort, Shell sort, whatever. Or use `qsort()` from the standard C library, as I often do.

Comment: @Stefan : i'm using f90 as fortran compiler, the program is never entering into the if statement that contain pause, so replace pause by write does nothing i guess

Comment: @Peter i launch code using java->jni->c->fortran, not easy to run all into a debugger :) i have a coredump that i can analyze but i m looking for how to run into a debugger...

Comment: @Vladimir i try to find another sort method to test thanks to all of you

Comment: How do you know, that it doesn't enter the `if`? The problem *could* be, that `jstack` get's larger than `NSTACK` and, thus, tries to access `istack` out-of-bounds. The result would be a segmentation fault. I would *guess*, that the requirements for `NSTACK` do not only depend on the length `n` of your input array, but also on the degree of order in your array, which would lead to the occasional crash.

Comment: if the compiler didn't support pause it wouldn't compile.  How do you know the problem lies in this subroutine?  Not that i'm a fan of numerical recipes , but I'd be surprised if it was not pretty robust.

Comment: hmm -- This code is not the same as in a more recent edition of the book.  (Very very similar looking but changed). Makes you wonder if the publishers fixed something or if someone monkeyed with your version.

Comment: @george : hello how can i find the most recent sort method to see the change? thanks

Comment: @stefan : i think if the program entering into the if, the program will pause and need a user intervention to continue no? i try to replace pause by write but nothing new :(

Comment: i have find a more recent sort method here : http://www.haoli.org/nr/bookfpdf/f8-2.pdf. but i have compilation problem, compiler doesn't compil because of Enddo 11 and enddo 12, i have replace them by "11 continue and 12   continue" and compilation pass. but program still have segfault. when i launch my program with only one thread, i don't have any problem, but in multi thread environment i still have this segfault...i suppose that this method doesn't support multithread no?

Comment: you can (should) simply remove the numbers (11,12), so you have just `do j=l+1,ir` .. and `enddo`.   *** if your issue is with threading you really should have said that in the quesiton ***

Comment: @george : sorry to don't mentionne that before but when i wrote the question, i don't have see this. so yes problem is in multi thread environement. so if you know problem about sort method in multi thread environment :)

Comment: This is basically a non-recursive implementation of a quicksort, which is why there is a check on the stack size.  It depends on how many items you are sorting - if it is less than 100, perhaps try something simpler that is not stack based like shellsort.http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Shell_sort#Fortran

Comment: why are you still using the old fortran77 version of sort. even numerical recipes has a newer fortran90 version. There are other open source libraries with sort(). I would suggest replacing your canned sort with other versions of sort and check if error appears again

Comment: @Jagte : hello, if all depends of me, i still use newer version of all :) but my client have persons whose are physicians etc.. and work in fortran. After that my client send me all fortran code to integrate it into the application... so i have no influence on the code. If i suggest them to use another sort method, they need to retest all the code, and they don't want to do that...so i m stuck and i need to find way to solve my problem :) and i have resolve my problem now. thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Too large for a comment:

Unfortunately the stack trace does not show the exact line of failure. What is the evidence that the error is at the line you indicated. I could imagine there could be error in calling the run-time system, sou you should try to change the `PAUSE` statement to `write`, `read *,` or something similar.

I did some tests with your subroutine in gfortran:

```
  parameter (n = 100000)
  dimension b(n)

  do i=1,1000
    call random_number(b)
    call sort(b,n)
  end do
end
```

with different array sizes and loop bounds. This calls the `sort` with many different inputs. I enabled all checks and sanitizations and didn't encounter a single problem.

**Edit:**

It works with OpenMP too:

```
  parameter (n = 100000)
  real,allocatable :: b(:)

  !$omp parallel private(b)
  allocate(b(n))
  !$omp do
  do i=1,1000
    call random_number(b)
    call sort(b,n)
  end do
  !$omp end do
  !$omp end parallel
end
```

Comment: this is possible to launch your test in multi thread environement or not?

Comment: But be careful, for multi-threading, you should use `recursive subroutine` or a compiler option that does it for you.

Comment: i compile with a makefile, it do : f90 -o $@ -g -c $< to compile .f object and then to do the .so: f90 -G -o LIB/libUtil_CADE.so obj/Numerical.o -L/opt/SUNWspro/lib -L/home/webadm/PAM/ctr -lfui -lfsu -lfai -lsunmath   i don't specify that my code is multi thread, but if you say that method work fine with openMp there is no problem... i have add -g option for the compiler and in gdb i can see value of istack(jstack) etc...i m looking this and i give you a feedback tkanhs

Comment: i have add some debugging information in my question and istack has strange value...

Comment: i have try to compil with  -stackvar option and i think its work for now, does this option can have a good impact for stack object?

Comment: Yes, `stackvar` could help, but seeing your debugging info, are you 100% sure the `n` you are passing to `sort` is correct? OR try to print the value of `k` it is maybe wrong for some reason.